# Davening behind someone who doesn't wait for me to finish

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei

If I have davened behind someone who davens faster than me, and he has consistently taken his three steps without waiting for me to finish ([which he should not do](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/34723/4794)), and seemingly does not mind taking three steps back into my 4 amos, [should I](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi) not daven behind them?  Is it lifnei iver for me to daven behind them?

Comment: daven slightly on the side of that person and it's fine acc to many

Comment: This has been a constant issue for me as well. I've taken to davening at the front of the Shul or far behind everyone else to avoid the problem. Modern shuls are often so packed (the tables are too close together) that people inevitably are praying in another persons 4 amos. We seem to consider the public to be mochel unless they specifically act otherwise. In that case, if it isn't bothering you, then it wouldn't be lifnei iver.

Comment: A person can't be mochel for the Shechina, there are two reasons for not backing up in front of someone davening, see Biur Halacha

Comment: There's a gemara about this. I'll try and find it

Comment: @sam And can the shechina conquer my trampling rights if I got there first?

Comment: [בית המדרש לתורה והוראה (ע.ר) אלון מורה](http://www.yelm.co.il/print.asp?id=66282) discusses a similar question – praying in part of the Beis Hamedrash where people normally walk and says:

וכתבו עוד שיש להיזהר מלהתפלל במעברים, שלא רק שע"י כן נפגם ריכוזו של המתפלל, אלא הוא גם מכשיל את הרבים, וכבר נאמר: "לפני עיוור לא תתן מכשול". 

And they write that one should not pray in the “corridors” because not only does one interfere with the concentration of the other people praying but also causes people to do the wrong thing and it already says “Do not cause the blind to stumble.”

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok There is a teshuvos maharsham that says it is assur to daven in the aisle and such, and says that there is therefore no issue to pass in front of someone who does. But I am asking about someone davening in their proper place, at their seat.

Comment: I am asking about someone davening in their proper place, at their seat.  Yes @YeZ that's why I posted it as a comment not as an answer. Thanks for the teshuvos Maharsham reference!

Comment: @sam Yet in the Beis Hamikdash itself they were jammed in like sardines! Omdim Retzufim Umishtachavim Revachim. Though we talk about the shechinah being sharoy in that daled amos, I don't think we are **halachically** concerned with the shechinah's presence or absense, only the interruption of another's tefillah

Comment: See the biur halacha on this inyun